# Connecting circles of the same color

Tags: unity, 2d, shaders

I've been following couple tutorials on making blobs with connected colors, and it works fine, but I have issues modifying it.

I'm spawning circles with dot gradient of certain color. Then in a shader I'm deciding which color to use above color value.

It works great for 3 colors.

**But I have no idea how to make it compatible with 4 or more colors.**
Right now I'm using rgb values above certain threshold.

I've tried both black and white but the fourth color behaves differently than the rest.

If it's impossible with my shader, then how else can I achieve this effect?

```
if (col.r > 0.3 && col.g > 0.3 && col.b > 0.3)
{
    return _Color4;
}
if(col.r > 0.3)
{
    return  _Color1;
}
else if(col.g > 0.3)
{
    return  _Color2;    
}       
else if(col.b > 0.3)
{   
    return  _Color3; 
}
```

[image: Blob colors]

Comment: You could do this with RGB + Alpha as your fourth, but to go above four you'd need a second texture.

Comment: Thank Your for suggestions, but unfortunately, alpha is problematic, because every color has alpha > 0.3 and if I change that, they will be invisible.

I also tried second render texture, but then it ignores other colors and goes behind them, instead of making a singular blob of colors.

Comment: No, you don't need alpha to represent the red, green, or blue channels in the source map (the one with the fuzzy gradients). They can be alpha-zero and still do their jobs. I used this technique to support the four different kinds of sky metaball in [The Weather Inside](https://dmgregory.itch.io/weather-inside), and just [wrote a shader that visualized alpha as white (with topographic contours)](https://twitter.com/D_M_Gregory/status/1258887992439115778) when I needed to debug it. It sounds to me like you need to separate the blob-forming steps from the composition with the background (later).